# how to find if a vector contains anything matching to regular expression

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I have questions related to project I am working on. I have thought about these, and have some suspicions, but I would love to hear the community's input as well.

I have a `std::vector<std::string> x` which contains some regular expressions like "^OPEN$" and "^CLOSE$". I also have a `std::vector<std::string> y` which contains some strings like "OPEN", "OPEN23", "CLOSE", "CLOSE4", "XS_234$".

Now i have to check if vector y has at least one matching the regular expression from vector x.

Limitations:

- No external supporting libraries (for example I can't use boost)
- No C++11 or newer.

Comment: If you can use C++11, you may be able to use `<regex>`.

Comment: @nneonneo - thats another limitation , i can't use C++11

Comment: You're going to have to use *some* regular expression library unless you want to write your own regular expression parser.

Comment: You claim to have some ideas. What are they?

Comment: Until C++11, there is no language/standard library support for regex. You have to roll your own. However, I suspect that this is an XY problem and that there is an easier way to solve the problem. Explain in your question why you need to use regex so that others can offer viable alternatives.

Comment: @Bill - actually i am using C++, QT , so my idea was to create a QString for each member in vector y and then see if the Qstring contains the regular expression from vector x something like this :for (int i = 0; i<devaiceNameList.size(); i++)
     {
        QString s = devaiceNameList[i].c_str();

       if(!s.contains(regExp))

Comment: @KaushikV: Or just use the regular expression library that is part of Qt: [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html)

Comment: std::string parameters = "^OPEN$;^SHORT$";QstringList madatoryDeviceNameList = QString(parameters.c_str()).split(";");for(int mandatoryNamesCntr = 0; mandatoryNamesCntr <madatoryDeviceNameList.size(); mandatoryNamesCntr++){QRegExp regExp(QString("^%1").arg(madatoryDeviceNameList[mandatoryNamesCntr].replace(QRegExp("\\$(?!\\])"), tr("[\\$]"))).replace(QChar('~'), tr("$"))); for (int i = 0; i<devaiceNameList.size(); i++){  QString s = devaiceNameList[i].c_str(); if(!s.contains(regExp)){//error}}}
 here devaiceNameList is vector y explained above initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QRegEpx](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html) will do the job. Create a **QRegExp** for each of your tokens, then run them against `x` to identify which one it is.

Then run `QString(y).contains(matchedRegExp)` to get your answer.

EDIT: you can also do:

```
QStringList list = QString(y).split(", ", QString::SkipEmptyParts).filter(matchedRegExp);
bool answer = list.size() > 0;
```

That way you have the list if you need it.